# Can't hot reload/hot restart flutter app on iOS device (WIRELESS debugging)

Tags: flutter, xcode, android-studio, debugging, hot-reload

I can (build &) run the application wirelessly from android studio to my iPhone, but once it's running, the hot reload button is greyed out. I also tried running it via terminal with `flutter run --debug` to make sure it's in debug mode, the button was still greyed out.

When I use the exact same device (iPhone) but via cable, not wireless, I can hot reload, that button is not greyed out.

I get the following output:

```
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         30.0s
Xcode build done.                                           328.8s
You may be prompted to give access to control Xcode. Flutter uses Xcode to run your app. If access is not allowed, you can change this through your Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation.
The Dart VM Service was not discovered after 75 seconds. This is taking much longer than expected...
Open the Xcode window the project is opened in to ensure the app is running. If the app is not running, try selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem.

Click "Allow" to the prompt asking if you would like to find and connect devices on your local network. This is required for wireless debugging. If you selected "Don't Allow", you can turn it on in Settings > Your App Name > Local Network.
If you don't see your app in the Settings, uninstall the app and rerun to see the prompt again.
Installing and launching...                                       120.1s
Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected...
Still attempting to connect to the VM Service...
If you do NOT see the Flutter application running, it might have crashed. The device logs (e.g. from adb or XCode) might have more details.
If you do see the Flutter application running on the device, try re-running with --host-vmservice-port to use a specific port known to be available.
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 192.168.178.195, port = 58939
This was attempt #50. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 192.168.178.195, port = 59081
This was attempt #100. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.
```

Comment: when running `flutter run --debug` from the command line, do 'r' / 'R' buttons work?

Comment: @pskink nope, pressing R does not do anything (except type R in the command line)

Comment: do you at least see something like this https://gpalma.pt/articles/1_J1l6S4RAzRMrqeZL9wYTQw.png ?

Comment: @pskink, nope, not at all

Comment: hmmm, too bad, any interesting info if you run `flutter run ...` with `-v` flag (verbose)?

Comment: @pskink that also didn't do it

Comment: I have the same problem on my Mac. How did you handle this ?